# Ler ArrayList que esta serializado

Tags: java, arraylist

Crio e instancio objetos do tipo aluno(classe abstrata), e adiciono no array. Logo apos isso, é feita a serializaçao do mesmo. Como posso desserializar este array, e imprimir o toString do mesmo, e usar outras funcionalidade, como fazer uma busca por nome ?

```
ArrayList<Aluno> ob = new ArrayList<>();

        Aluno tres = new Aluno_Graduacao("Pedro", "Silva", 2, "Tads", 2015, 10);
        ob.add(tres);

        Aluno o = new Aluno_Graduacao("Stanley", "Henrique", 2, "Tads", 2015, 10);
        ob.add(o);


        Aluno quatro = new Aluno_Graduacao("Costa", "Marcelo", 2, "Tads", 2015, 10);
        ob.add(quatro);



        Aluno dois = new Aluno_Graduacao("Maria", "Silva", 2, "Tads", 2015, 10);

        ob.add(dois);


        try{
            FileOutputStream oo = new FileOutputStream("Arquivo.txt", true);
            ObjectOutputStream oob = new ObjectOutputStream(oo);

            oob.writeObject(ob);
            oob.close();


            FileInputStream ler = new FileInputStream("Arquivo.txt");
            ObjectInputStream lerr = new ObjectInputStream (ler);

            //Aqui é onde nao consigo achar a solucao 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá voce tem de atribuir a um objeto do mesmo tipo que era antes de serializar conforma a baixo e usar o metodo `readObject()`. Recomendo fortemente o uso de try-resources para fechar seus recursos automaticamente.

```
try(FileInputStream ler = new FileInputStream("Arquivo.txt");
ObjectInputStream lerr = new ObjectInputStream (ler)){

ArrayList<Aluno> listaDeserializada =(ArrayList<Aluno>) lerr.readObject();

} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```